# PHP Code works on shared hosting but not on Xampp

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I have a PHP application developed using the Codeigniter framework.

My application works perfectly find on my shared hosting service (Hostgator) but doesn't work right when developing locally with Xampp.

I've attached a screenshot showing an example of what I see with Xampp vs what I see on my web host.

Stuff I've tried so far:

- Double check DB settings
- Reinstall Xampp (did this like 5 times...)
- Restart computer
- Check Xampp apache error logs (nothing useful in there)
- Check to see if ports were occupied by another service
- Set my base URL in codeigniter and add virtual hosts to apache config files
- Edit hosts file to point virtual hosts to localhost

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my code for the above image:

```
<?if($this->data['site_logo']!=''):?>
      <img SRC="<?=$this->data['site_logo']?>" alt="<?=$this->data['site_name']?>" />
<?endif;?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use short tags when outputing data: <?=$userName?> should replace <?php echo $userName; ?>. Short tags shouldn't be used for other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable short tags, head in to your php.ini file, find the line with:

```
short_open_tag = 0
```

and change it to

```
short_open_tag = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Shorttags seems to be disabled on xampp.

Simply add a php after the question mark. Every PHP part should start with

```
<?php
```

The more correct version for

```
<?=$var?>
```

is

```
<?php echo($var); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always use long PHP tags:

```
<?php if($this->data['site_logo']!=''): ?>
      <img SRC="<?php echo $this->data['site_logo'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->data['site_name'] ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Well, in terms of development time, it's much easier to code with short tags and make sure they're enabled on your server.  If you're hosting with someone who won't let you enable them, that's a good sign you're hosting in the wrong place.

Comment: No you should not always use long PHP tags. In the new PHP versions short tags are enabled by default.

Comment: @SamDufel it's not 1960s anymore - we have enough space in our HDDs to save couple more characters and we also have good IDEs which will turn three keystrokes <?[enter] to a nice <?php ?> tags for you.

Comment: It's not a matter of hard drive space - it's a matter of extra typing and extra characters to sift through.  If you prefer to use long tags, go crazy - however, server configuration shouldn't be a deciding factor on which style you use.

Comment: @SamDufel Your code with <?php will work everywhere, but <? will work only on some servers. I think that is the most important part. Even the official PHP documentation discourages the use of the short form: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: As of the newest version, short tags are on by default, and the short echo syntax (`<?=`) is always usable, regardless of the short tag setting.  In older versions, they can be enabled in an htaccess file, a vhost file, or the main php.ini file.  It's really *not* that hard to activate them - less difficult than say, configuring the `mail()` function.

Answer (score 1):

have you configured your XAMPP to allow the short `<?` tag in stead of the default `<?php` tag?

Comment: Thanks Peter. It seems that the xampp php.ini file has shorttags disabled by default. To solve this I set short_open_tag to On in xampp\php\php.ini

Answer (score 0):

`<?= ?>` is the problem, change to `<?php echo ?>`